# Inno Setup: is it a script based deployment program?

Tags: inno-setup, setup-deployment

I am using Inno Setup for the first time.  When I start the program I am presented with a blank script page.  Is scripting the only way you can create a setup package?  Is there anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Inno Setup is script-based (thank God -- this really makes things a lot easier if you ask me). But there is a "wizard" that lets you create a new setup by a simple step-by-step approach in a simple GUI. Simply choose "Create a new script file using the Script Wizard" in the "Welcome" dialog box that appears when you start the Inno Setup Compiler.

If you have disabled the Welcome dialog box, use File/New instead to start the wizard.

## Update

I was just informed about the new [InnoIDE](http://www.innoide.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Inno Setup is script based. If you want a GUI Builder then you may check the site ["Third-Party Files"](http://www.jrsoftware.org/is3rdparty.php) on Inno Setups Homepage.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to start is with one of the example scripts included with the install.

Just change the product name in the sample and you are set for 90% of basic installs